# How can I make Users submit only one vote?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have to make a Website where users can vote only once. I tried to register them in my db using their IP address with `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` but i did some research and found out that in some cases multiple users can have the same IP (using the same wifi or the IPS sharing IP's between them). Also, i don't want them to make an account to be able to vote, or log in with facebook, google, etc...

Is there any way to do this with PHP?

Comment: Store details of whether user has already voted or not in browsercookie. In most cases it will work, as users are unaware of cookies. If somebody tries to use incognito mode or clears browser data, then it will fail.

Comment: You could identify them via a cookie or some device based specifications. Neither of this is perfectly reliable.

Comment: You can use a combination of storing the ip address, setting a cookie and the user name. This is not an absolute solution but it is getting harder to bypass.

Comment: I will use both IP and cookies and hope for the best, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just have a quick glance at https://github.com/samyk/evercookie. Your search will end there.

Comment: thanks! i will try this and come back with an update

Answer (score 1):

You can store to DB a fingerprint and then compare it like you did before with an IP address
https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs
or u can make your own fingerprint by storing user's device, it width,height,timezone,etc
But it'll fail if someone will vote with other device.
I think it must works like an Antifraud systems, but they're based on the same way I wrote.

Comment: While @sunil singh answer is more practical this answer grantees more accurate solution not bulletproof but still really good